# Django view not recognizing request

Tags: python, django, request

I have a form that is filled out on a webpage. The goal of the form is to gather some basic info, and then save the IP of the sender to the DB too.  The form submits a POST request to my Django view, but Django gives me the error:

```
if request.method() == 'POST':
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is the view:

```
from .form import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):

    if request.method() == 'POST':
         form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
         if form.is.valid():
             signup_item = form.save(commit=False)
             signup_item.ip_address = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
             signup_item.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls.import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from form import views

 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'', views.index, name='home')
 ]
```

Comment: ` url(r'', views.index, name='home).`  did you miss a single quote at the end?

Comment: @haifzhan that was a copying mistake, corrected now

Comment: `request.method` is not a function, it is a string. Get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: @FamousJameous doh! thanks, im oblivious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with request.method(); method is a string data member, not a member function. Remember - this is python, where 'getters' are often dropped in favor of directly accessing class members.

So, try:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
```

etc.